# Need to click on absolute element and trigger 2 click events: 1 for the absolute element and other for the element behind it

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Can I trigger `click` events for both of these elements?

- `position: relative` container

  - **ELEMENT 1:** regular div
  - **ELEMENT 2:** `position: absolute` div

IRL the element 2 is a transparent backdrop that is there to listen for clicks on top of the header to hide a nav drawer. But if the user clicks on the Header logo, I want to hide the nav drawer but I also want to navigate to the homepage.

Is it possible? What could be a work around for this?

```js
function App() {
  
  function handleClick1() {
    console.log('From handleClick 1 behind div...');
  }
  
  function handleClick2() {
    console.log('From handleClick 2 absolute div...');
  }
  
  return(
    <div className="container">
      <div className="normal" onClick={handleClick1}>
        Only the absolute DIV click is fired.
      </div>
      <div className="absoluteDiv" onClick={handleClick2}>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
div.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

div.normal {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.absoluteDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(55,55,55,0.3);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: I do not understand what you actually want ? You want when you click, both of the elements to be clicked in the same time ?

Comment: You think about it in a wrong way. Your event logic should happen higher. So let's say you have parent container for both elements you want the event to "trigger" but this is not actually what do you want - in react data changes view, so let's say you change with click event "eventFired: true" and if it's true than change CSS of elements you want to collapse. And use lifecycle methods to know when to redirect to other route.

Comment: You guys are right. I did end up handling it on a higher level. But I was still curious if this "trick" is possible. But I guess it's not.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what are you trying, or something similar.

```js
function App() {
  
  const handleClick1 = ()  => {
    console.log('From handleClick 1 behind div...');
  }
  
  const handleClick2 = () => {
    handleClick1();
    console.log('From handleClick 2 absolute div...');
  }
  
  return(
    <div className="container">
      <div className="normal" onClick={handleClick1}>
        Only the absolute DIV click is fired.
      </div>
      <div className="absoluteDiv" onClick={handleClick2}>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
div.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

div.normal {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.absoluteDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(55,55,55,0.3);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: Not exactly. I don't know for sure where the user could click. If they click on the logo, I want to navigate, but if they click at some empty space on the header, then I just want to close the drawer. But thanks!